# In Unity, how can I pass values from one script to another?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, I want one object to have a falling speed variable that all the other objects can access. For various reasons, I can't use the inbuilt gravity for what I'm trying to do.

**How can I access a variable in one object repeatedly, so that when it updates I get the updated variable, from another object?**

Comment: Declare it in the global scope? I thought Unity used javascript, but the `C#` tag throws me off.

Comment: @JanDvorak In Unity you can use UnityScript (their version of javascript) or C#.

Comment: Unity can use JavaScript, C~ or Boo (a pythonesque, fairly new language)

Comment: I believe `c#` has a static (class-local) scope that you can use. Perhaps this is where you should place it.

Comment: I need to define a new class for every script though. Within a script, I can easily pass values, I just don't know how to do it from outside.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.

If you want the speed variable controlled by a component which is attached to a GameObject `MyObject`

```
public class SpeedController : MonoBehaviour
    public float speed;
    // maybe you want restrict this to have read access, then you should use a property instead
```

In other classes you can do:

```
GameObject go = GameObject.Find ("MyObject");
SpeedController speedController = go.GetComponent <SpeedController> ();
float courrentSpeed = speedController.speed;
```

Take care that there is one object named MyObject only otherwise things get messed up.

Alternatively you can define a `SpeedController` member in every class that needs access to `speed` and set a reference via drag and drop in Unity editor. You save the lookup then but of course this is pretty inconvenient if needed in many classes.

---

Another way is to create a singleton which holds the `speed` variable and have:

```
public class MyGlobalSpeedController {
    private static MyGlobalSpeedController instance = null;
    public static MyGlobalSpeedController SharedInstance {
        get {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new MyGlobalSpeedController ();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
    public float speed;
}
```

So all classes can access this:

```
float currentSpeed = MyGlobalSpeedController.SharedInstance.speed
```

---

As Jan Dvorak stated in comments section:

```
public class SpeedController : MonoBehaviour
    public static float speed;
```

---

**[Update]**
Thanks to Jerdak. Yes [Component.SendMessage](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Component.SendMessage.html) should be definitely on the list:

```
go.SendMessage("GetFallingSpeed");
```

Again you need to have a reference to `go` like described in the first solution.

There are even more solutions to this problem. If you are thinking of game objects that are active in all scenes, you should have a look at [Unity singleton manager classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730112/unity3d-singleton-manager-classes)

Comment: Don't forget [SendMessage](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Component.SendMessage.html)  It's def. not the best option but it's useful on occasion.

Comment: I keep getting this error: 'error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property' (I am using your first method)

Comment: Here:  SpeedController speedController = go.GetComponent<SpeedController>();

Comment: @Dakeyras Seems like you are doing it in initialisation of a member variable. Maybe [A realy easy c# question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/186981/a-realy-easy-c-question.html) sheds some light on it.

Comment: The part with the property is wrong. The property is static while the field is not so it cannot return it since it cannot access it.

Comment: It's a [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). `MyGlobalSpeedController.SharedInstance` returns an instance and `speed` is the field of this instance.

Comment: go.SendMessage("GetFallingSpeed");

how could this works? send message doesn't have return value

Answer (score 5):

If I were you I would just make this speed variable "static public" so you can access it from anywhere. You should always avoid "find.anything" etc functions, they are quite slow. There is no reason for you to look for something that you exactly know where it is.

Comment: I'm reading these answers and wondering what is wrong with this one?

Answer (score 2):

> if it is in the fixedUpdate – Martin j

seems like it works well in Awake too. Both scripts are added to the same GameObject.

```
public class FirstScript : MonoBehaviour {
    protected internal GameObject myobject;
private void Awake() {
       myobject = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("nameofprefab"));
       myobject.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
...
```

```
public class SecondScript : MonoBehaviour {
    private GameObject myobject;
private void Awake() {
       myobject = gameObject.GetComponent<FirstScript>().myobject;
       myobject.SetActive(false); //for example
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
other.GetComponent<class name>().object name;
```

Comment: if it is in the fixedUpdate