# Shared variables in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 c# scripts in my game. On of them is in my "main player object" and the other script is in "my main camera". I want to declare a float variable in the script of my main player, and in every game second i want to record the x position of my player in that variable and at the same time passing this value to the my main camera's script and assigning this value into the x position of my main camera in every game second. How can I pass a variable to a script from another one ? Or how can i create a variable which can be used by any script in my game ?

Comment: There are a few ways to handle this. One is to make a public Transform/GameObject variable on the camera script, and drag the player object onto it in the Unity inspector. Then, you can use it to access the `transform.position.x` of the player. That's the simplest solution for your case, no extra scripting needed on the player script itself. However, this would only make this variable accessible to the camera script - if you need it accessible from all scripts in your project you'll need to approach this differently.

Comment: Do what Tom says.  This question has been asked 1000 times!

Answer (score 2):

There's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891892/in-unity-how-can-i-pass-values-from-one-script-to-another) that explains this problem in great detail, but the simplest way that is included in that answer would be to do something like the following:

```
public class Speed: MonoBehaviour
    public float speed;
    // maybe you want restrict this to have read access, then you should use a property instead
```

And then in other scripts:

```
GameObject gameObject = GameObject.Find ("Some object");
Speed theSpeed = gameObject.GetComponent <Speed> ();
float mySpeed= theSpeed.speed;
```

Comment: Second way is look like more safer. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, if this has helped you make sure you tick the answer! :-)