# I want to create scoring system (Unity 2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, scoreloop

I'm making 2D Game like Pac-Man. Nevertheless, I have some issues to create a scoring system.

I want to update score whenever my Pacman eat coin(a.k.a pacdot)

I made C# script called 'ScoreManager'

Here is code

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour {

    static int score = 0;

    public static void setScore(int value)
    {
        score += value;
    }

    public static int getScore()
    {
        return score;
    }

    void OnGUI ()
    {
        GUILayout.Label("Score: " + score.ToString());
    }
}
```

This code is working well when I play my game in Unity engine

But, I don't know how to set up ScoreValue in Pacdot scripts.

Here is Pacdot Code

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Pacdot : MonoBehaviour {

    public int score = 10;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D co) {
        if (co.name == "pacman")
        {           
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

    }
}
```

Also, I added C# Script ( Pacmanbehaviour )

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PacmanMove : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 0.4f;
    Vector2 dest = Vector2.zero;

    void Start() {
        dest = transform.position;
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        // Move closer to Destination
        Vector2 p = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, dest, speed);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MovePosition(p);

        // Check for Input if not moving
        if ((Vector2)transform.position == dest) {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && valid(Vector2.up))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position + Vector2.up;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) && valid(Vector2.right))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position + Vector2.right;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) && valid(-Vector2.up))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position - Vector2.up;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && valid(-Vector2.right))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position - Vector2.right;
        }

        // Animation Parameters
        Vector2 dir = dest - (Vector2)transform.position;
        GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("DirX", dir.x);
        GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("DirY", dir.y);
    }

    bool valid(Vector2 dir) {
        // Cast Line from 'next to Pac-Man' to 'Pac-Man'
        Vector2 pos = transform.position;
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Linecast(pos + dir, pos);
        return (hit.collider == GetComponent<Collider2D>());
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Unity, how can I pass values from one script to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891892/in-unity-how-can-i-pass-values-from-one-script-to-another)

Comment: Is your ScoreManager script attached to something like a score board, currently?

Comment: yes, my score is displayed on Screen like score : 0

Comment: Is the ScoreManager script attached to the display object?

Comment: No... I tried ..but failed

Comment: How can I put ScoreManager code in Pacdot Script?

Comment: As long as the ScoreManager is either part of a game object, or it's own game object, a variation on the answer below should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ScoreManager script needs to live as a game object, or as a component in a game object. Then you can add it as a field in your Pacdot class.

It'll be something like this below, but finding the specific game object the script is attached to will depend on how you have it designed (the "find by tag" approach won't work unless you have a game object with ScoreManager attached, with that tag).

```html
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Pacdot : MonoBehaviour {

    public int score = 10;
    private ScoreManager _score = GameObject.findGameObjectWithTag("scoreKeeper").GetComponent<ScoreManager>();

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D co) {
        if (co.name == "pacman")
        {           
            _score.SetScore(score);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

    }
}
```

I would also look at the answer @derHugo linked to--a lot of ways to accomplish this, depending on your needs/design.

Comment: Fantastic! Glad to help. Feel free to accept the accept as well so it's easier for people coming after us to tell if there's a solution :)