# Trouble Sharing Variables between files in c#

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble finding out how to share variables between different c# files. I'm relatively new to coding in this language and i don't know how to access a Boolean from one file in another.

I can provide code if needed, i'm using unity if that matters.
I'm being told that the variable doesn't exist in current context.
ask if more info is needed i don't really know what you nee to answer this.

this is the first file

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



public class floorAndWallCheck : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool isGrounded = false;

    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D floor){
        if (floor.tag == "floor") {
            isGrounded = true;
        }else {
            isGrounded = false;
        }
    }
}
```

this is some lines from second file

```
void Update () {
    //left
    if (Input.GetKey("a")) {
        player1.transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
    //right
    if (Input.GetKey("d")) {
        player1.transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
    //up
    if (Input.GetKey("w") && isGrounded == true) {
        player1.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * jumpForce);                       
    }
```

Comment: You need to learn a lot more about C# and programming. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/) is a good place to start. There is no such thing as "C# file" - all this "files" are compiled into an assembly (usually one) and after that they exist in a .net CLR (Common Language Runtime).

Comment: Thanks! i Will be sure to check it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/25932315/7111561 .. this was answered so many times already

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing a variable from another script C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930919/accessing-a-variable-from-another-script-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems that you might want to check `isGrounded` for multiple players I would **not** use `static` as mentioned in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54395037/7111561) since then it is static for every instance of `floorAndWallCheck`.

---

Instead you have to access the member of the according instance.

Assuming the `floorAndWallCheck` component is e.g. attached to the `player1` object you can do

```
private floorAndWallCheck player1FloorCheck;

private void Awake ()
{
   player1FloorCheck = player1.GetComponent<floorAndWallCheck>(); 
}

private void Update()
{

    //...

    Input.GetKey("w") && player1FloorCheck.isGrounded)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

or instead of using `GetComponent` you can make it either public

```
public floorAndWallCheck player1FloorCheck;
```

or use `[SerializeField]`

```
[SerializeField] private floorAndWallCheck player1FloorCheck;
```

and reference the according component in the Inspector (via drag & drop)

---

Find more ways for accessing other classe's members [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13892844/7111561)

Answer (score 1):

Here it looks like you want to use static

```
public class floorAndWallCheck : MonoBehaviour {
    static public bool isGrounded = false;

    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D floor){
/// etc
```

Then in the other file

```
if (Input.GetKey("w") && floorAndWallCheck.isGrounded == true) {
```

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/statics

The problem is that this will make the variable global to **all** instances of a floorAndWallCheck

I don't think you want that even if you are asking for it in your question.  Probably what you really want to do is not "share the variable"  but instead have a variable of that type be a parameter to whatever function you were using in the 2nd file.  In this way you can "pass" the data from one place to another.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will test it tommorrow after work.

Comment: It doesn't have to be static necessarily .. I would rather recommend to access the correct instance of `floorAndWallCheck`

Comment: @BaileyAnderson - Hogan's answer is more about what to avoid. You shouldn't use `static` is the bottom-line - it will cause you problems. You should find out how to reference the specific instance. A full [mcve] would be useful in your question.

Comment: Static is usually not the best solution, particularly with beginners. But in this case, it is fine since there would be only one floorAndWallCheck component over the whole application. Now if that component is to be used on multiple objects then static is no longer valid.