# Approach for updating points by multiple actions in game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to game programming. I am working on a game in which user points can be updated by multiple actions (like completing 10 meters, coins collections etc). Can anybody help me what approach can I follow here to update points as there are multiple actions which can update same variable at the same time

Comment: This question needs more detail. You might also try searching http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Place the score within a static class; dispatch events; use `lock()` if you encounter issues with thread safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the overall points and the kind go in a static variable while the level related points are instantiated in the game manager.

The best approach is to make your game manager as a singletone class (see [Unity singleton manager classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730112/unity3d-singleton-manager-classes)) and put there a static AddPoints(int) method. That will solve nicely your problem without any concurrence problem because Unity processes the classes and methods sequentially, so it's impossible to have concurrency issues in a class inheriting from MonoBehaviour.