# Accessing Derived Singleton Instance Throws Compiler Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, singleton, polymorphism

I am trying to implement a Singleton base class in my Unity3d project. But attempting to access the instance of a Singleton raises compiler errors:

`Type 'Singleton' does not contain a definition for 'getPlaneTextureType' and no extension method 'getPlaneTextureType' of type 'Singleton' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

**Do I need to override the method/property `instance` for each class that derives from Singleton?** Ie, change the return type to the child class type? Or is there 1 simple change I can make to the base class `Singleton` that will fix this? Like for example; using c++ like templates?

```
public class Singleton : MonoBehaviour {
    #region Static Variables
    private static Singleton _instance = null;
    #endregion

    #region Singleton Class Generation
    public static Singleton instance {
        get { return _instance; }
    }

    protected Singleton() { }

    void Awake() {
        if (_instance != null) {
          GameObject.Destroy( this );
          return;
        }

    _instance = this;
    }
    #endregion
}

public class TerrainManager : Singleton {
    public PlaneTexture getPlaneTextureType() { }
}

// Usage that throws compiler error: Type 'Singleton' does not contain a definition for 'getPlaneTextureType' and no extension method 'getPlaneTextureType' of type 'Singleton' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
TerrainManager.instance.getPlaneTextureType();
```

Comment: Alternatively look at [Unity3D singleton manager classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730112/unity3d-singleton-manager-classes/13731328#13731328)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you want a Singleton in Unity to be just a plain Singleton Design pattern without it being a MonoBehaviour.

Othertimes you need your Singleton to be a MonoBehaviour. When it must be a MonoBehaviour you can do this to avoid calling `new` which you can't do on MonoBehaviours.

### Solution

#### Makes a Singleton out of a MonoBehaviour

```
public class Singleton : MonoBehaviour
{
   private static Singleton _instance;

   // Will be called before anything, don't even worry about it, instance be initialized.
   void Awake()
   {
      _instance = this;
   }

   public static Singleton getInstance()
   {
      return _instance;
   }
}
```

This should also allow you to inherit from this Singleton like this:

```
public class Singleton2 : Singleton
{
}
```

Also the `Destroy()` code you are using won't be a good idea unless you are protecting the Singleton from being destroyed on level change with [DontDestroyOnLoad()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html)

---

### Other Solution

You can find it here: [**Unity Wiki Singleton**](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton) It is the same code Imran posted but he forgot to include the reference link where he got it from.

Comment: There are some issues regarding Solution 1 and I would not recommend to use that:  **1.)** A derived class may implement its own `Awake` and the pattern is broken because of Unity's SendMessage strategy; Use the `sealed` modifier to prevent this. **2.)** That said `Awake` is no longer available in derived classes ;-) Provide a `protected virtual InternalAwake` method and call it in 'Awake' so that derived classes can override this **3.)** `getInstance` method might return null when calling from another component whose Awake method is called first.

Answer (score 0):

You can either move `getPlaneTextureType()` method into the `Singleton` class for `TerrainManager.instance.getPlaneTextureType()` to work you can change `getPlaneTextureType()` into a static method and called it as such... `TerrainManager.getPlaneTextureType()`.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance won't help you implement a singleton in C# very well. The reason is that if you put the static field in the base class, it is the same static field for across all inherited classes. This exactly what you don't want. You want a static field and/or property in each inherited class that is different.

It's not really that much code to implement one in the first place so inheritance isn't really letting you reuse a lot of code. This is your basic singleton template:

```
public class Singleton 
{
    private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() { }

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return instance; } }
}
```

I would just copy and paste that every time I needed one, but I find myself using the singleton pattern only sparingly.

Comment: Yes, I haven't used it much till Unity3d. You can attached a script to a GameObject very easily so its really easy to accidentally or ignorantly create many 'Manager' classes. So by designing the 'Managers' as Singletons I can use design to avoid this problem. But I'm trying to remove alot of repeating code by not having to paste each singleton functionality code into each class (about 8 times).

Answer (score -1):

generally you applying singleton for

**"It is a design pattern that restricts the Instantiation of a class to one object. And, if you're here, you probably want to use that basically for implementing Global Variables. For any other usage"**

Now try  for [implementation](http://unitypatterns.com/singletons/)

Other help plz [link](http://unitypatterns.com/singletons/)

Comment: Could you please include the link where you copy pasted the code from? I found it for you here: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton We don't want to think you are plagiarizing.

Comment: I forgot to add reference for singleton pattern in unity please check