# Why doesn't this count the points, that the player collected correctly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables

I am making a game, similar to the one in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5NWZoTSjWs&list=PLPV2KyIb3jR53Jce9hP7G5xC4O9AgnOuL&index=11

I am trying to implement collectable "objects" that give you more points (3 of them on one level) So I used a variable gemCounter, that increases by one every time the player collides with the "gem"

What's wrong? On every trigger, the code returns 1 as the result...

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dOub.png)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GemTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SphereCollider Sc;
    public MeshRenderer Mr;

    public int gemCounter = 0;

    private void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        gemCounter += 1;
        Mr.enabled = false;
        Debug.Log("Gem " + gemCounter + " detected");
    }
}
```

Comment: This counter should be a property on the player. It doesn't make sense for a trigger to maintain a count like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each instance of `GemTrigger` has its own copy of the `gemCounter` field because it's not a static field.

One change you could use is making `gemCounter` static with:

```
public static int gemCounter = 0;
```

Or, better yet, put `gemCounter` in a [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730112/unity-singleton-manager-classes) and have all of the `GetTrigger` instances modify the `gemCounter` in that singleton.

Comment: Thanks, still thinking, how dumb I was, trying static int without public...

Answer (score 1):

Another option you have would be to attach gemCounter to the player object.  Then you could tag the player with "Player" and add a script potentially called "PlayerController" and use

```
GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerController>().gemCounter+= 1;
```

This will allow you to keep track of the gemCounter from the player as opposed to on each individual gem.